# How to create custom facet labels with both bold and math expressions using facet_wrap in ggplot2?

Tags: r, math, ggplot2, label, facet

I've been working on this for days and can't seems to find a reproducible code (or even a lead) on how to do this. Long story short, I'm trying to create a publication quality figure in which I want my facet labels to look like this (although the -1 should be superscript :/):

**(A)** Decomposition rate (g·d^-1)

So I want my facet labels to both have a bold text, plain text, and math component. I'm using facet_wrap instead of facet_grid because I want to be able to specify the number of columns/rows. While I know how to make axis labels and such like this using

```
lab=expression(paste(bold("(a)")~plain("Decomposition rate")~"(g"%.%d^-1")"))
```

I can't just change the variable levels/names in the data frame b/c then ggplot2 doesn't recognize the bold and math expressions. Any leads or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: is this helpful https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/labeller

Comment: best option would probably be tikzDevice